# Windows 8.1 x64 update stuck

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, windows-update

When I manually 'check for updates' , it gets stuck on 'checking for updates'

I read that I should install KB3112336 manually, but the standalone installer also gets stuck on 'searching for updates on this computer'

And above all both take 17% CPU (100% of a single virtual core)

I'm pretty much losing fate in Windows

help me please

Comment: `KB3112336` was released over a year ago.  Are you certain it wasn't superceeded with a different patch?

Comment: do some search, I already answered this. stop WU service before installing a MSU update